# Eclipse cannot build an apk, error with build path

Tags: java, android, eclipse, buildpath

I am using the newest version of eclipse. When I try project -> clean in console I get these two errors:

```
[2014-04-15 16:17:27 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2014-04-15 16:17:27 - MyFirstTryWithEQ1] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

I spend quite a lot of time to find way out, but unsuccessful.

P.S. Looks like it is because of /bin in the build path, but I don't know how to remove it. Also I am getting this error: the container 'android dependencies' references non existing `'/Users/gintas/Documents/workspace5/google-play-services_lib/bin/google-play-services_lib.jar'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will be a finally fix.**

> 1. Close eclipse.
> 2. Delete bin folder inside your project folder.
> 3. Start eclipse and clean your project.
> 4. Now run and the problem should begone.

*Even now you are getting the same error.Please consider updating the Eclipse IDE.*

Comment: I've tried, but I can't. It requires reputation 15, so I've just done what I can - marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: Its OK.Just change your display name and fill your details.You will get a AutoBiographer Badge.

Answer (score 0):

that because you have a duplicated library file. you may remove the duplicated library from your libs folder

Comment: But I can find only one android-support-v4, so don't see what to remove.

Comment: do you have any dependencies projects ?

Comment: Yes, I have just found, that actionbar has support-v4-19.0.0.jar and main project has android-support-v4.jar, so can it be the cause? But when I try to delete one or other it cause other errors.

Comment: you may delete jar file from your project not the dependence project

Answer (score 0):

Just open Expand the project's root node.Show in eclipse

> You can now see a Bin. Just Expand it Now you can see a folder named
>   "dexedLibs". Just Expand that node. You can see some libraries. Just
>   check for any duplicate entries. (Please check it carefully and make
>   sure you are not deleting any unduplicate entry).

Eg:-
You can find like this.

> **bin/dexedLibs/android-support-v4-773c629b8eb1e89bdd821a2c07db8998.jar**

If you have found any duplicate entries.Just delete that and rebuild your project.

It seems this will help you.

Comment: Sadly, but I can't find also that dexedLibs folder in bin

Comment: Is it possible, that actionbar's support-v4-19.0.0.jar and main project's android-support-v4.jar are causes of my problem?

Comment: What do you mean about that.There is no dexedLibs folder.Are you compiling your project for the first time.

Comment: I am working first time with eclipse, so maybe I don't know where to look for dexedlibs, because in package explorer -> actionbarsherlock/bin I can see only androidManifest.xml, res, R.txt, actionbarsherlock.jar. There is no folder called dexedLibs

Comment: Just open the project folder in windows explorer.And search for that folder you will find it.

Comment: Ok, I have found it now, but which I should to delete? http://postimg.org/image/fdt3nc5yr/

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the support-v4...jar in the dexedLibs folder.
Because there are two libraries for same functioning.
For some eloboration delete the library file that is marked in the below picture.[image]

Comment: I deleted it but when I try to start application it recreates itself in dexedLibs.

Comment: Yes after recreating itself.What is the error.Please give me the details of what is printed on the console.For detailed research

Comment: On the console I get:
>[2014-04-16 17:30:29 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>[2014-04-16 17:30:29 - MyFirstTryWithEQ1] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

If I would clean project in the problem section temporary I can see errors "the container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library'